# How do I add a checkbox for custom field repeater?

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

My current code, it works.

MY goal:

I want to have a checkbox for "not available" sizes, so if I check the box it will add the class="na" for the tr row, so it will have the color gray.
How do I achieve that?

**Size Guide**
[image]

```
<section class="row-wrap">
    <div class="row-inner">
        <table class="size-guide" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>UK</th>
                    <th>EU</th>
                    <th>Chest(cm)</th>
                    <th>Chest(in)</th>
                    <th>Height(cm)</th>
                </tr>

                <?php

                // check if the repeater field has rows of data
                if( have_rows('size_guide') ):

                    // loop through the rows of data
                    while ( have_rows('size_guide') ) : the_row(); ?>

                        <tr class="na">
                            <td><?php the_sub_field('uk'); ?></td>
                            <td><?php the_sub_field('eu'); ?></td>
                            <td>$<?php the_sub_field('chest_(cm)'); ?></td>
                            <td><?php the_sub_field('chest_(in)'); ?></td>
                            <td>$<?php the_sub_field('height_(cm)'); ?></td>
                        </tr> 

                    <?php endwhile;

                else :

                    // no rows found

                endif;
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- /size guide -->
```

Comment: From PHP can you add a extra class to the `<tr>` which has data and does not has data? If so then I can help you with simple jQuery trick.

Comment: Can you help me with the jQuery trick? How do i add the extra tr tag in PHP? :)

Comment: Is the given code is your full PHP code?

Comment: yes it is. why?

Comment: because according to your code all the `<tr>` should have `na` class but in you image only the last 2 row has `na`.

Comment: The image one is my design.

Comment: What is the name of the field that decide that you have value for a particular field or not?

Answer (score 0):

Ok say you added a checkbox to your repeater field called available. You would just check that checkbox value. If it equals no add your na class.

```
<tr class="<?php if (get_sub_field('available') === 'No') {echo 'na';} ?>">
    <td><?php the_sub_field('uk'); ?></td>
    <td><?php the_sub_field('eu'); ?></td>
    <td>$<?php the_sub_field('chest_(cm)'); ?></td>
    <td><?php the_sub_field('chest_(in)'); ?></td>
    <td>$<?php the_sub_field('height_(cm)'); ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do I add the checkbox in the custom fieldsets?

Comment: Yes just add another field and choose checkbox for the field type like you did for uk, eu, chest_(cm), chest_(in), and height_(cm).

Comment: Ok right now i see the checkbox but when i check one of them nothing happen.

Comment: When I inspect it i don't see the class . Inspect look like this <tr class>

Comment: Do you know why?

Comment: What did you name the field do you have a link to where I can view this? Can you update your original question with your new code, and show a screenshot of your field?

Comment: read about how to setup and use your checkboxes properly here : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/checkbox/